# Fn::Sub with a Mapping in a literal block to specify the user data script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Ok so reading the documentation on the The intrinsic function Fn::Sub.  I can use a literal block to specify the user data script.

```
UserData:
    "Fn::Base64":
    !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash -xe
        yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
        /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource LaunchConfig --configsets wordpress_install --region ${AWS::Region}
        /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource WebServerGroup --region ${AWS::Region}
```

and I can uses a mapping to substitute the ${Domain} variable with the resulting value from the Ref function.

```
Name: !Sub
    - www.${Domain}
    - { Domain: !Ref RootDomainName }
```

But what if I need to use a mapping substitute *inside* a literal block?  Like for example:

```
"Fn::Base64": !Sub |
    <powershell>
        Write-host "My Domain is www.${Domain},{ Domain: !Ref RootDomainName }"
    </powershell>
```

This example does not work, and I haven't been unable to find a method that does.  Any ideas?  The first example makes userdata scripts much easier to write and looks cleaner, but without being able to to use !Ref or !Findinmap it's usefulness is reduced dramatically.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Since I arrived to this page through Google, and then found the solution through a different wording here(literally):
[How to use !FindInMap in !Sub | userdata section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506363/how-to-use-findinmap-in-sub-userdata-section)

I'll just add it to save some frustrated searching to others.

Essentially, you have to write your example using the 2nd syntax but a bit more verbosely:

```
Fn::Base64:
  Fn::Sub:
    - |+
      <powershell>
        Write-host "My Domain is www.${Domain}"
      </powershell>
    - Domain:
        Fn::Ref: RootDomainName
```

You may be able to shorten it a bit, but as the original poster said, mind your commas, quoting and usage of short forms.

P.S.: If the first solution has already served your purpose, you should mark it thus.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you would write it simply as ${RootDomainName}. Local resouces in the same stack can just be mapped by using their resource name.

Comment: What if one wanted to use !GetAtt inside the the literal block?

Comment: Then you do the same thing: ${Resourcename.Attribute}

Comment: This is such a deeply underrated answer, thank you!