# How to use !FindInMap in !Sub | userdata section

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Currently I  am converting CFT from JSON to Yaml. Everything works fine until Userdata section.I am having hard time to use any of functions like !Ref or !FindInMap in userdata section.

**UserData:**

```
Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        #!/bin/bash -v
        /command {Fn::FindInMap: [ "url", Ref: AWS::Region, Ref: EnvironmentType ] }
```

It would be very helpful, If anyone can share any snippet of code.

Answer (score 26):

I've been having fun and games with this as well. Although [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) says that `Fn::FindInMap` is supported in `Fn::Sub`, there's no example of use and I've tried all sorts of combinations of quotes and colons without success, but I finally seem to have hit upon a functional solution using mappings. The following should work:

```
Fn::Base64: !Sub
  - |+
    #!/bin/bash -v
    /command ${Url}
  - Url:
      Fn::FindInMap:
        - UrlMap
        - !Ref AWS::Region
        - !Ref EnvironmentType
```

The pipe at the start of arg0 tells YAML to preserve newlines, and the plus tells it to keep a newline afterwards.
Arg1 tells it to substitute the result of the `Fn::FindInMap` for the Url in arg0.

The following shorter version should also work:

```
Fn::Base64: !Sub
  - |+
    #!/bin/bash -v
    /command ${Url}
  - Url:
      Fn::FindInMap: [UrlMap, Ref: "AWS::Region", Ref: EnvironmentType]
```

But you should test that. Note the commas, quotes, and reversion to `Ref:`s rather than `!Ref`s. This probably tells us something about how the files are being pre-processed, but I'm not sure what that is.

I'm sure that this solution is obvious to experienced YAMLers, but I was only just starting to get my head around JSON when all this YAMLy goodness was added to CloudFormation.

Comment: AWS has now added a documentation page regarding the same.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-fn-sub-function/

Answer (score 4):

I had similar use case: Substitute value from map for corresponding parameter value. If parameter value doesn't match the mapping entry, use default value.
Here's my working sample, hope this helps.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String
    Description: The environment.

Mappings:
  envResourcesMap:
    dev:
      someHost: "hostVal_D"
    staging:
      someHost: "hostVal_S"
    prod:
      someHost: "hostVal_P"
    other:
      someHost: "hostValm_XXX"

Conditions:
  IsDevEnv: !Equals
    - !Ref Env
    - dev
  IsStagingEnv: !Equals
    - !Ref Env
    - staging
  IsProdEnv: !Equals
    - !Ref Env
    - prod
  IsStandardEnv:
    Fn::Or:
      - Condition: IsDevEnv
      - Condition: IsStagingEnv
      - Condition: IsProdEnv

Resources:
  storeSSM:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Description: !Sub "DESC for ${Env}"
      Name: !Sub "/Global/ssmpath/someHost"
      Type: String
      Value: !Sub
        - ${spiderman}
        - spiderman: !If [
            IsStandardEnv,
            !FindInMap [ "envResourcesMap", !Ref Env, "someHost" ],
            !FindInMap [ "envResourcesMap", "other", "someHost" ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me

```
UserData :
  Fn::Base64 : !Sub
  - |
    #!/bin/bash -v
    export some_variable = ${url}
  - url : !FindInMap [Mapping, !Ref AWS::Region, !Ref EnvironmentType]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  UserData :
    Fn::Base64 : !Sub
    - |
        #!/bin/bash
        echo "test ${SetTopologyScript}" >> /home/ec2-user/test.logs
    - SetTopologyScript : !FindInMap [ MappingName, !Ref "AWS::AccountId", SetTopologyScript ]
```

You can refer to this complete userdata snippet. Here the Parameter in the Mapping section is `SetTopologyScript` which has three say sections of dev, qa and prod, represented by the AWS AccountIDs